# Mounted CIFS directory by web shell not visible in the system shell

Tags: shell, mount, apache-httpd, php

I use PHP `shell_exec` to run the command

`echo password | sudo -S mount.cifs //192.168.1.15/Share /share -o username=root,password=password`

HTTPD user is granted sudo-pivilege, the command ran successfully without error. After checking mounted places by using `mount` command, it came with some interesting results.

1. The `mount` command execute by PHP `shell_exec` show CIFS directory, I can `ls` or `cp` files and folders from my SAMBA server to HTTP server.
   [image]

   But when I SSH to HTTP server and run `mount` as `root`, the CIFS directory was not there. I can't access to `/share` directory at the same time I able to do it in the web shell.
2. If I restart HTTPD service and re-run `mount` command in the web shell, mounted Directory **gone**. I think what I saw in the web shell is a temporary process.
3. In order, I can `mount` 2 times by using `web shell` then use `system shell`and `umount` 2 times as well without effect the mounting list of the another, it's like 2 separate systems.

   If I do it in reverse order, `system shell` first then ->  `web shell`, nothing weird at all.

Why is this and How to make it visible in the system by using web shell?